# Return the documents if the array field length greater than 0 in esclient nodejs

Tags: node.js, arrays, elasticsearch, search, filter

I have millions of documents in my es index.
I wanted to fetch the documents where the array field length greater than 0.
My docs looks like this

```
[
    {
        "primaryKey": "9c30d9e8-af04-4cc8-afcb-0c1311988c1e",
        "language": "all",
        "industry": [
            "Accounting & auditing"
        ],
        "text": "what's the status of my incident?",
        "textId": "d0c70fc4-5e2a-4cab-a5f6-32339e6632dd",
        "extractions": [],
        "active": true,
        "status": "active",
        "createdAt": 1620208485092,
        "updatedAt": 1620208485092,
        "secondaryKey": "5db5f725-ec09-49da-9507-7bb2f94fd741"
    },
    {
        "primaryKey": "9c30d9e8-af04-4cc8-afcb-0c1311988c1e",
        "language": "all",
        "industry": [
            "Accounting"
        ],
        "text": "What is the rating of my incident",
        "textId": "4a53533f-293e-440c-aaa9-f7e5ae1436ca",
        "extractions": [
            {
                "name": "Abinas Patra",
                "role": "api-user",
                "primaryKey": "ed12851d-c18d-4c92-8cc3-1782e41bc9d0"
            },
            {
                "name": "Anil Patra",
                "role": "ui-user",
                "primaryKey": "933fad33-78b3-4779-a7bd-c62c6e02af75"
            }
        ],
        "active": true,
        "status": "active",
        "createdAt": 1620208485092,
        "updatedAt": 1620208485092,
        "secondaryKey": "5db5f725-ec09-49da-9507-7bb2f94fd741"
    }
]
```

I am using [elasticsearch nodejs client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch).
I tried in the below way

```
let dataCount = await esClient.count({
    index: "indexName",
    type: "docType",
    body: {
        query: {
            bool: {
                must: [
                    {
                        "script": {
                            "script": {
                                "inline": "doc['extractions'].values.length > 0",
                                "lang": "painless"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "primaryKey": {
                                query: primaryKey,
                                "operator": "and"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "language": {
                                query: language,
                                "operator": "and"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I get runtime parsing error everytime, i tried with exist field as well.

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"script_exception","reason":"runtime error","script_stack":["org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:65)","org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:27)","doc[\'extractions\'].values.length > 1","    ^---- HERE"],
```

tried this as well

```
must_not:[
    {
        "script": {
            "script": "_source.extractions.size() > 0"
        }
    }
]
```

Can anyone please help here.
thanks :)

Comment: what parsing error do you get?

Comment: updated in the question.